# Giving positions name in django automatically

Tags: python, django

I'm building a bus booking website using Django. I have an attribute position in my table 'seat'. It is linked to bus(table) by ForeignKey. Whenever a bus is created, seat instances are created equal to the capacity of the bus(capacity is defined by the user in bus table). I want to name the positions like 1_1, 1_2, 1_4, 1_5, 2_1, 2_2, 2_4, 2_5 etc.. where the first digit before underscore represents row and digit after underscore represents a column. I'm not using 3 because it's the aisle.

> this is my models.py

```
class Seat(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Seat"
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    bus = models.ForeignKey(Bus)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=(('available', 'available'), ('reserved', 'reserved'), ('unavailable', 'unavailable'),), default='Available')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0}-{1}-{2}'.format((self.bus),(self.id),(self.status))

@receiver(post_save, sender=Bus)
def create_seats(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        for seat in range (0, int(instance.capacity)):
            instance.seat_set.create( )
```

> This is how the naming of position is done

[image]

as you can see it's empty in the middle so for that 3rd column is not used. My question is how can automatically name the positions (like I create seats whenever a bus object is created) according to the chart without having to go in individual seat object and name the position. I hope you get my question. If you need any more info please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes the buses can have different seat layouts, which means you’ll need to define the seating pattern for each bus type.

The most basic way would be to define them as constants, as 2-dimensional lists/arrays, entering 1 for a seat and 0 for no seat:

```
#seating_patterns.py

BUS_1 = [
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
]

BUS_2 = [etc]

SEATING_ARRAYS = {'BUS_1': BUS_1, 'BUS_2': BUS_2}
```

To make this more maintainable you could create a SeatingPattern model, for instance with an ArrayField if that is an option for you.

Otherwise import the seating arrays into your models file:

```
# models.py
from .seating_patterns import SEATING_ARRAYS
```

and add a seating_pattern field to your bus model, with a choices tuple for the buses:

```
class Bus(models.Model):
…
SEATING_PATTERNS = (
    ('BUS_1', 'BUS_1'),
    ('BUS_2', 'BUS_2'),
)
…
seating_pattern = models.CharField(choices=SEATING_PATTERNS, max_length=50)
```

And create the correct format output (1_1, 1_2, etc) like this in your post_save signal:

```
if created:
    seating_pattern = SEATING_ARRAYS[instance.seating_pattern]
    for row,seats in enumerate(seating_pattern):
        for pos,seat in enumerate(seats):
            if seat:
                Seat.objects.create(
                    bus=instance,
                    position="{}_{}".format(str(row+1), str(pos+1))
                )
```

Comment: it produces this error 'Select a valid choice. [[1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]] is not one of the available choices.'

Comment: OK I've edited the code a bit - this should work now. See the changes to SEATING_PATTERNS, the new SEATING_ARRAYS and changes to the post_save signal. I couldn't get the bulk_create to work so now it creates the objects in a loop - you might want to try and change that if it's a performance issue. Also, the better way to save the seating arrays is in an ArrayField which I believe is only available if you're using a Postgres database.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the bus layout is always the same:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Bus)
def create_seats(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        for place_num in range(1, int(instance.capacity)+1):
            row = (place_num // 5) + 1
            col = (place_num % 5) + 1
            if col != 3 and row*col not in [24, 25]:
                instance.seat_set.create(position='%i_%i' % (row, col))
```

Comment: and if the layout changes?

Comment: if the layout changes you can use an approach like the one suggested by  @birophilo

Comment: it produces this error 'Select a valid choice. [[1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]] is not one of the available choices.'